# Asynchronous Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, asynchronous

I have a DataGrid control on webpart. DataSource of it connect to SQL. How can we use Asynchronous mode in this case ? 
Please help me !

Thanks / Phong Dang.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial may be helpful:

http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-To-Create-AJAX-enabled-SharePoint-Web-Part-with-UpdatePanel-and-UpdateProgress-in-10-minutes.aspx